# Dynamic class creation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any possibility to use a single block of code ( a single class as reference ) to create multiple classes? I am imagining something like this:

```
const List classes = [ClassOne, ClassTwo, ...];

class ClassX extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClassX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ClassXRoute()), 
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Likes")
```

then the following will be created:

```
class ClassOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClassOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ClassOneRoute()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Likes")

class ClassTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClassTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ClassTwoRoute()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Likes")
```

Also consider that some other variables in class may depend on the dynamic name. EG:

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ClassTwoRoute()),
```

Comment: Why not use objects and pass the desired route as a parameter?

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to achieve this.

const List classes = [ClassOne, ClassTwo, ...];

```
abstract class ClassX extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClassX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget getRoute();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => getRoute()), 
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Likes")
```

Then you can extend this class like

```
class ClassOne extends ClassX {

   const ClassOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   Widget getRoute() => ClassOneRoute();
}

class ClassTwo extends ClassX {

   const ClassTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   Widget getRoute() => ClassTwoRoute();
}
```

Let me know if this is something you want to achieve.

Comment: that is not class generation.

Comment: I know this isn't class generation. The question is whether the OP knows if something like what he wants to achieve can be achieved in the following manner. Class generation would be bad idea if it can be solved by solution posted.

Comment: really helped. thanks!